# Error - New-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy : 1032: ConditionalActionPolicy validation failed due to InvalidControls

Tags: json, azure, powershell, cloud

Whenever I try and run this json file to create a conditional access policy for geoblocking, it keeps coming back with:

```
 New-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy : 1032: ConditionalActionPolicy validation failed due to InvalidControls.
    Status: 400 (BadRequest)
    ErrorCode: BadRequest
    Date: 2023-09-13T22:10:38
    Headers:
    Transfer-Encoding             : chunked
    Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
    Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
    request-id                    : 68fdbd3b-3a45-4ddb-956a-7e8e6fed69e4
    client-request-id             : 23bfe620-7fb8-4c4b-925d-e7d2c4a3d2c0
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US 2","Slice":"E","Ring":"1","ScaleUnit":"004","RoleInstance":"MW2PEPF0000E056"}}
    Cache-Control                 : no-cache
    Date                          : Wed, 13 Sep 2023 22:10:38 GMT
    At C:\\Users\\MarkKearney\\OneDrive - Netsmart Inc\\Documents\\CondAccess\\Deploy-Policies.ps1:295 char:9
    
    +         New-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy -BodyParameter $request ...
    
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ body = Micros...lAccessPolicy }:\<\>f__AnonymousType0\`1) \[New-MgIdentityC...ssPolicy_Create\], Exception
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadRequest,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy_Create
```

Here is the JSON file.

```
{
    "displayName": "Netsmart - <RING> - Geoblock - Outside US & Canada",
    "createdDateTime": null,
    "modifiedDateTime": null,
    "state": "enabledForReportingButNotEnforced",
    "sessionControls": null,
    "conditions": {
        "signInRiskLevels": [],
        "clientAppTypes": ["All"],
        "platforms": null,
        "locations": {
            "excludeLocations": ["15b3734a-b51f-4aa9-b76d-4d3a137222ba", "18bde4b6-cb0d-45ea-8058-9578d3ace326"],
            "includeLocations": ["All"]
        },
        "deviceStates": null,
        "applications": {
            "includeApplications": ["All"],
            "excludeApplications": [],
            "includeUserActions": []
        },
        "users": {
            "includeUsers": ["All"],
            "excludeUsers": [],
            "includeGroups": [],
            "excludeGroups": [],
            "includeRoles": [],
            "excludeRoles": []
        }
    },
    "grantControls": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "builtInControls": [],
        "customAuthenticationFactors": [],
        "termsOfUse": []
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im pretty new to Azure and JSON -> Azure Conditional Access policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> New-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy : 1032: ConditionalActionPolicy validation failed due to InvalidControls.

The error message you received indicates that the `Conditional Access policy` you are trying to create has invalid controls (`InvalidControls`). When I attempted to create a `Conditional Policy` by passing an empty value, I also encountered the same error as you.

[image]

The `"builtInControls"` should contain `one or more built-in` controls that specify what actions should be taken.

To resolve this issue, you should specify at least one valid `built-in control` that defines what action should be taken when the conditions are met. Common built-in controls include `"block"`, `"allow"`, `"requireMFA"`, and others.

```json
    {
        "displayName": "Geoblock - Outside US & Canada",
        "createdDateTime": null,
        "modifiedDateTime": null,
        "state": "enabledForReportingButNotEnforced",
        "sessionControls": null,
        "conditions": {
            "signInRiskLevels": [],
            "clientAppTypes": ["All"],
            "platforms": null,
            "locations": {
                "excludeLocations": ["15b3734a-b51f-4aa9-b76d-4d3a137222ba", "18bde4b6-cb0d-45ea-8058-9578d3ace326"],
                "includeLocations": ["All"]
            },
            "deviceStates": null,
            "applications": {
                "includeApplications": ["All"],
                "excludeApplications": [],
                "includeUserActions": []
            },
            "users": {
                "includeUsers": ["All"],
                "excludeUsers": [],
                "includeGroups": [],
                "excludeGroups": [],
                "includeRoles": [],
                "excludeRoles": []
            }
        },
        "grantControls": {
            "operator": "OR",
           "builtInControls": ["block"],
            "customAuthenticationFactors": [],
            "termsOfUse": []
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once the above script was executed, the `Conditional Access Policy` was successfully created in the portal.

[image]